# LinkedList from scratch, replacing a node

Tags: java, linked-list

I was given an assignement to create a LinkedList from scratch, I've figured how to code a method that add a node at the end of the list but I still can't figure how to replace a node. Here is what I have so far:

```
public boolean replace(int element, int index) {
        Node temp= new Node(pElement);
        Node current = getHead();
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            temp.setNext(noeudCourant.getNext());
            noeudCourant.setNext(temp);

            listCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Using *aNode.replace(10, 4)* on  "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"

will make it into

> [0]->[1]->[2]->[3]->[4]->[**10**]->[5]->[6]->[7]->[8]->[9]->[10]

but I want:

> [0]->[1]->[2]->[3]->[**10**]->[5]->[6]->[7]->[8]->[9]->[10]

Any help is appreciated.

[edit]I already have a working method setData() but the assignment I have forbid me to use it. What I want is basically this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaW0T.png

Comment: You want to replace the Node or delete it? From *"but I want"* it seems that you want to delete the node at location `4`.

Comment: @Scota Koa , Check my answer below. it works same as specified in the link http://i.imgur.com/oOVYCvc.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code. I have written the logic in comments wherever required.

```
public boolean replace(int element, int index) {
    Node temp= new Node(pElement);
    Node current = getHead();
    if (!isEmpty()) {

        //Run for loop one less than index value.
        for (int i = 0; i < index -1 && current.getNext() != null; i++) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        // At this point current points to element 3.
        // Set next element of node 4 as a next element of new element 10.

        temp.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

        // at this point we have two references for element 5 like below
        // [0]->[1]->[2]->[3]->[4]->[5]->[6]->[7]->[8]->[9]->[10]
        // [10]->[5]->[6]->[7]->[8]->[9]->[10]

        // Set null to next element of of element 4 to remove reference to
        // element 5
        current.getNext().setNext(null);

        // At this point we have two list as below:
        // [0]->[1]->[2]->[3]
        // [10]->[5]->[6]->[7]->[8]->[9]->[10]

        // Set new element as next of current element (current element is 3)
        current.setNext(temp);

       // here we have replaced the element 4 with element 10

        listCount++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think it work but when you are doing : current.getNext().setNext(null) you're setting the next element of 10 and not 4 to null

Comment: Shouldn't you set it to null after temp.setNext(current.getNext().getNext())

Comment: @ScotaKoa As I said below, this won't work if you have to replace a value at index `0`.

Comment: @kamal What if you pass `index` greater than the nodes in the list? This code will never return `false` in that scenario and will probably replace the value at wrong index!

Comment: @user2004685 , You are right. I have not concentrated on boundary conditions. I have given an answer by considering his problem statement. It is also because it is partial code and the usage of the method !isEmpty() and variable listCount is not clear. Also the main intention of Scota Koa is to understand how it can be done and he understood it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to replace the Node and do not delete it then here is how you should be writing your `replace()` function:

```
public boolean replace(int element, int index) {
    Node head = getHead();
    int counter = 0;
    while(null != head && counter++ < index - 1) {
        head = head.getNext();
    }

    if(null == head || null == head.getNext()) return false;

    Node newNode = new Node(element);
    newNode.setNext(head.getNext().getNext());
    head.setNext(newNode);
    return true;
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that you have `setNext()` method in your `Node` class to set the link.

Also note that here it is assumed that you'll never replace `head` itself i.e. you'll never replace the element at index `0` or else you'll have to return the new `head` from the function.

Comment: I already have a working method setData() but the assignment I have forbid me to use it

Comment: @ScotaKoa Well that is what I understood of `replace()`. If you want to create a new node out of the element and replace the links then look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for your question:

```
package linkedlist;

class Node {
    public Node next = null;
    public int element;

    public Node(int el) {
        element = el;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    public Node first = null;

    public void add(Node node) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
        } else {
            // Traverse to the last
            Node cursor = first;

            while (cursor.next != null) {
                cursor = cursor.next;
            }

            cursor.next = node;
        }
    }

    public void add(int[] elements) {
        int len = elements.length;

        for (int i=0;i < len;i++) {
            add(new Node(elements[i]));
        }
    }

    public boolean replace(int element, int index) {
        Node cursor = first;
        Node prev = null;

        while (cursor != null && index >= 0) {
            index--;
            prev = cursor;
            cursor = cursor.next;
        }

        if (index > 0) return false;

        if (prev != null)
            prev.element = element;

        return true;
    }

    public void displayAll() {
        Node cursor = first;
        while (cursor != null) {
            System.out.print(cursor.element + " ");
            cursor = cursor.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prepare elements
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
        linkedList.add(new int[]{0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10});

        println("Display the initial linked list content:");
        linkedList.displayAll();

        println("After replace:");
        linkedList.replace(10, 4);
        linkedList.displayAll();

        println("Done");
    }

    static void println(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```